# opencv Kalman filter multiple object tracking error

Tags: c++, image, opencv, kalman-filter

I have been trying to work on multiple object tracking using Kalman Filter. Here is my code,

```
for (int i =0; i<vGlobal.size(); i++) // Vector of objects of interest
    {
        cv::Point pTemp = cv::Point(vGlobal[i].iX, vGlobal[i].iY);
        cv::KalmanFilter kTempKF(4,2,0);
        kTempKF.statePre.at<floatt>(0) = pTemp.x;
        kTempKF.statePre.at<float>(1) = pTemp.y;
        kTempKF.statePre.at<float>(2) = 0;
        kTempKF.statePre.at<float>(3) = 0;

        kTempKF.transitionMatrix = *(cv::Mat_<float>(4,4)<< 1,0,1,0,  0,1,0,1,  0,0,1,0,  0,0,0,1);
        cv::setIdentity(kTempKF.measurementMatrix);
        cv::setIdentity(kTempKF.processNoiseCov, cv::Scalar::all(1e-4));            
        cv::setIdentity(kTempKF.measurementNoiseCov, cv::Scalar::all(10));
        cv::setIdentity(kTempKF.errorCovPost, cv::Scalar::all(.1));
        vKalmanFilters.push_back(kTempKF);  
    }
```

I am using vector of Kalman filters to track each of my objects. I have done initialization of the filters as above. Now I try to work on predition and measurement as follows in the below code.

```
 for (int i=0; i<vKalmanFilters.size();i++)
    {
        cv::Mat mPrediction = vKalmanFilters[i].predict(); 

        cv::Point pPredict(mPrediction.at<float>(0), mPrediction.at<float>(1));
        mMeasurement(0) = vGlobal[i].iX;
        mMeasurement(1) = vGlobal[i].iY;


        cv::Mat mEstimated;


            mEstimated = vKalmanFilters[i].correct(mPrediction); // Run time Error occurs here


     }
```

When I try to run this program, I get a runtime error in the  correct(Prediction)

```
  OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (C.type() == type && (((flags&GEMM_3_T) == 0 && C.rows == d_size.height && C.cols == d_size.width) || ((flags&GEMM_3_T) != 0 && C.rows == d_size.width && C.cols == d_size.height))) in gemm, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 741
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
 what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:741: error: (-215) C.type() == type && (((flags&GEMM_3_T) == 0 && C.rows == d_size.height && C.cols == d_size.width) || ((flags&GEMM_3_T) != 0 && C.rows == d_size.width && C.cols == d_size.height)) in function gemm
```

I am still a beginner in Kalman Filter. The error occurs at the point of prediction. Is my approach totally wrong ? Please someone explain where I am going wrong.

Comment: Matrices should be `float` (CV_32F) or `double` (CV_64F), not `int`

Comment: @Berriel: Yes, it worked. But now (as edited newly), a different run time error occurs at the correct(Prediction) step, which I added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `mMeasurement` (2x1 matrix) instead of `mPrediction` (4x1 matrix) in the [correction step](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#kalmanfilter-correct):

```
mEstimated = vKalmanFilters[i].correct(mMeasurement);
```

Given that you did:

```
cv::KalmanFilter kTempKF(4,2,0);
// 4 dynamic params <-- your state, e.g. [x y dx dy]
// 2 measurements params <-- your mMeasurement [x y]
```

Comment: How can I use prediction then ? I thought Prediction also should give 2x1 matrix. I was told that, If there is no measurement, then Prediction will be the solution. So prediction also gives the similar kind of value as Measurement does. How to get the predicted values if there are no measurement values ? This is my question.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please accept or upvote it. About your doubt, KalmanFilter uses a measurement in the correction step, which updates the predicted state based on that measurement. In case of a missing measurement, it is up to you to decide. Sometimes, people use the last predicted state to `correct()`, but before doing this, I advise you to understand what is really happening, mathematically. Also, in this case, the state is 4x1 and you just need the first 2 to use as a `measurement`.

Comment: hi, this doesn't work for me. I am getting wrong estimated values. However if I declare KalmanFilter object globally I get correct estimated value and that too if I have only one blob. If I have two blobs I get two same estimated value at the center of both blobs. How would I make the estimated values to follow their respective blob? could you please help me.